# Powershell scripting for url custom monitoring

Tags: powershell, url, monitoring

I am trying to build a custom script for URL monitoring. I am able to run the URL's from the file and enter the same in a logfile(named with time stamp).
Till here I have completed

Issue is when I compare the values from present(present timestamp) and previous logfile(previous timestamp).

This portion is not working fine. Please help me correct it.

Here is my code trying to compare value line by line from present logfile and previous logfile and run commands to generate output:

```
# New log is new logfile data
$Newlog = Get-Content $URLlogfile

$old_file = Dir C:\Scripts\logs | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select Name -last 1

# Old log is Old logfile data
$oldlog = Get-Content $old_file -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Foreach($logdata in $Newlog) { 

    $url = ($logdata.Split(" "))[0]
    $nodename = ($logdata.Split(" "))[1]
    $statuscheck = ($logdata.Split(" "))[2]
    $description = ($logdata.Split(" "))[3]
    $statuscode = ($logdata.Split(" "))[4]

    Foreach($log1data in $oldlog) {

        $url1 = ($log1data.Split(" "))[0]
        $nodename1 = ($log1data.Split(" "))[1]
        $statuscheck1 = ($log1data.Split(" "))[2]
        $description1 = ($log1data.Split(" "))[3]
        $statuscode1 = ($log1data.Split(" "))[4]

        While ($url = $url1) { 
            if ($statuscheck = $statuscheck1 ) {
                write-output "output is same"            
            } elseif ($statuscheck = Fail) {
                While ($statuscheck1 = Pass) {
                    write-output "$url is down at $nodename1- testing event sent"
                }
            } elseif ($statuscheck = Pass) {
                While ($statuscheck1 = Fail) {
                    write-output "$url is up at $nodename1- testing event sent"
                }
            }
        }
        Break
    }    
} 

#At end am clearing the old logs except present one

dir C:\Scripts\logs -recurse | where { ((get-date)-$_.creationTime).minutes -gt 3 } | remove-item -force
```

Comment: One large issue I see is that `=` is the not equality comparison operator. You want to use `-eq` in your `if` and `while` statements.

Comment: You realize there are a ton of monitoring tools already built. I wouldn't recommend building your own. Believe me, people have done this for a long time :) Trying to use log analytics to monitor service availability is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Jonah, Yes I agree with the same. But am just playing around to find something different... Just a baby step towards something big

Answer (score 1):

Per the comment from BenH, the following part of your code needs correcting as follows:

```
If ($url -eq $url1) { 
    if ($statuscheck -eq $statuscheck1 ) {
        write-output "output is same"            
    } elseif ($statuscheck -eq 'Fail' -and $statuscheck1 -eq 'Pass') {
        write-output "$url is down at $nodename1- testing event sent"
    } elseif ($statuscheck -eq 'Pass' -and $statuscheck1 -eq 'Fail') {
        write-output "$url is up at $nodename1- testing event sent"
    }
}
```

**Corrections:**

- In your comparison statements the `=` needs to be `-eq`. In PowerShell = always assigns a value.
- In your comparison statements Pass and Fail need to be surrounded by single quotes so they are treated as strings (otherwise they are treated like function statements, for functions which don't exist).
- I've replaced the `While` statements with `If` statements. I'm not sure what the intent of those was but I think they'd just get stuck in an infinite loop as the variable they test is never changed from within the loop.

Comment: thank you Mark.

I have made the corrections recomended. but still my output is not complete

Please find the complete script which i have updated. I am able to run the url monitoring with 1st segment and log the same in a log file named with time stamp. 
Secondly I am comparing the outputs from present and previouly generated logfile and i am printing output only in case of state change
Third, I am deleting the old logfiles and keeping the recently generated.

second segment is not behaving as it should be....

Comment: It would be best to open a new question for this, with your revised script.